# Getting error that @Gedmo\Timestampable was never imported, even though it was

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities: one, called `Event`, that *is* timestampable (through Gedmo) and has been for months, and another that is *not* timestampable yet, called `User`, but that I'm trying to make timestampable.

At the top of my `User` entity, I have the following `use` statement:

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
```

And then I have this:

```
/** 
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/** 
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
 */
private $updated;
```

This is the exact same way that I'm doing it for `Event`. Strangely, though, when I try to do `./app/console doc:mig:diff`, I get this error:

> [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
>   [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Gedmo\Timestampable" in property
>   VNN\PressboxBundle\Entity\User::$created was never imported. Did you
>   maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

No, I didn't forget to add a `use` statement. I find it bizarre that `Event` worked just fine some time ago but now `User` isn't working. Why could I be getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this strange behaviour and I don't remember what exactly caused this.

How do you load doctrine.extensions config in app/config/config.yml ?

Here is my well working configuration :

`app/config/config.yml`:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.ini }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: doctrine-extensions.yml }
```

`app/config/doctrine-extensions.yml`:

```
services:
    gedmo.listener.timestampable:
        class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
        tags:
            # I have 2 DBAL connections using Timestampable
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: tm_vg }
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: tm_common }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ '@annotation_reader' ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem to resolve it I replace

`@Gedmo\Slug(fields={"projectName"})`

by

```
@Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Slug(fields={"projectName"})

/** 
 * @Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Slug(fields={"projectName"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```